# Hiding navigation bar causes the view to shift up

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

When I hide the navigation bar the whole view shifts up.
I need to hide my navigation bar but i want my view to maintain its position.

is there a way to maintain that spacing without having a navigation bar there?

Comment: how did you hide your navigation bar? Please show some codes

Answer (score 1):

You can set the color of NavigationBar as transparent like this

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

for `swift`

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage! = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Comment: is there no way of doing it without actually hiding, in my case, the navigation bar needs to be explicitly hidden

Comment: If you want this then you need to set your constraints without using NavigationBar in your Storyboards or XIB.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your `view` constraint to `Top`, not `Top Layout Guide`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to make your navigationBar hide:

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true
```